# How can I call a random number in multiply places in a way that each random number has a different value?

Tags: javascript

So I want to change 4 "a" element background-color and I want to use rgb colors in a way that each color has a random generated number,so the colors will be different every time I call with a function.The problem is that the generated number not changing but use the same random number on all element so it's colors the same.

I could fix that by putting random numbers in an Array and call random numbers from there but it's kind of complicated.

To sum it up:

-I'm looking for a more compact solution to do that

-I also want to use some other method to call this function individually on every element...not in this querySelectorAll way...

Hope everything was clear and Thanks for the answers!:)

```
function changeCol() {
    var colors = document.querySelectorAll(".con a");
    var x =[255,180,45,99,191,11]
    var y =[25,210,67,49,101,22]
    var z =[156,194,55,9,88,33]

    if(x==x2 || y == y2 || z ==z2){

        return;
    } else {

     colors[0].style.backgroundColor ="rgba("+x[Math.ceil(Math.random()*5)]+","+x[Math.ceil(Math.random()*5)]+","+x[Math.ceil(Math.random()*5)]+")";

     colors[1].style.backgroundColor ="rgba("+x[Math.ceil(Math.random()*5)]+","+x[Math.ceil(Math.random()*5)]+","+x[Math.ceil(Math.random()*5)]+")";

     colors[2].style.backgroundColor ="rgba("+x[Math.ceil(Math.random()*5)]+","+x[Math.ceil(Math.random()*5)]+","+x[Math.ceil(Math.random()*5)]+")";

     colors[3].style.backgroundColor ="rgba("+x[Math.ceil(Math.random()*5)]+","+x[Math.ceil(Math.random()*5)]+","+x[Math.ceil(Math.random()*5)]+")";
    }

   x=x2;
   y=y2;
   z=z2;
}
```

Comment: imo putting numbers in an array and then shuffling it will be the easiest way to approach this I think

Answer (score 1):

JS `Math.random()` return a random number between 0 and 1. So you are getting a random number between 0 and 1, after doing `ceil()` always it is 1. Thats why you are getting always same number.

But you can get random number by setting a range like

```js
function getRandomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
}

console.log(getRandomInt(6))
```

[**MDN reference**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random).

Answer (score 1):

The function will generate a new color whenever called

```
function getRandomColor() {
  var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
  var color = '#';
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
}
```

And code will be a lot simpler

```
var colors = document.querySelectorAll(".con a");
colors.forEach(element => {
    element.style.backgroundColor = getRandomColor()
})
```

Comment: Thank you,it's worked!:) But can you explain me what does the "element" var do?Because it does'nt have a value.I know it's represent the array elements,but why exatcly?Is it working like this in a normal function or what?

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll(".con a") ` will return the list of `elements` and to iterate through them have to use `forEach` and `element` var represents the single element in `colors` var

Answer (score 0):

if you need random color(s) you can use [randomcolor](https://github.com/davidmerfield/randomColor).
we have used in several projects without problems.